# Dealing with singletons/modules with local state when Server Side Rendering JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, design-patterns, server-side-rendering

In JS all modules are cached (by Node directly or by Webpack in a browser, for example) so essentially they're all singletons by default.

Some of them sometimes contain a state, like the module in this example:

```js
// foo.js

let state = 0;

export function incrementNumber() {
  state++;
}

export function getNumber() {
  return state;
}
```

The issue with these is that when they're made for the client-side, the assumption is that the state will only be global for that specific browser tab session - once the page is refreshed/left, the state is gone. However, if you try to Server-side render a JS App that has modules like this, the stateful singleton is going to act differently and the state is going to leak between all users.

Considering that I have a client-side Vue application that has some modules like this and I want to implement SSR - what would be the best way to refactor such modules so that they work correctly? I need the component to be a singleton in the client-side, but I don't want there to be invididual instances of it for each separate request in the server-side.

Comment: Can you show us where and how you call these functions (in a typical way)?

Comment: "*I need the component to be a singleton in the client-side*" - do you really? Yes, you'll want to create only a single instance on the client side, but that doesn't necessitate making a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with module singletons.
Fortunately we don't have that many of them. So far we are refactoring all of them and we try to keep essential singleton data into redux state or somehow inside of react app context like inside of component.

Good luck!